# how can i draw on the minimap

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

I would like to draw on the minimap but all i archived so far is pinging and pinging with a message (like top is missing).
Some people in chat told me i need to double click something but i just did not get it.

Could someone please explain it in detail what i need to do to draw on the minimap?

Furthermore can i draw freely on the map or only in straight lines? (I only saw lines so far)

Comment: I assume you've tried the dota 2 way before asking

Comment: @WizLiz yes ctrl + leftclick does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt+Left Click the minimap as if you were pinging, and immediately 'ping' again on another part of the map. It'll draw a white, straight line. You can add a 3rd 'ping' for a 2nd straight line.

To my knowledge, the lines cannot be shaped or curved, etc.

You also have to give it a few seconds before re-drawing, presumably to prevent people from spamming it.

Comment: i tried it but it did not work for me. it seems that the feature is bugged at the moment: http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/showthread.php?494723-How-can-you-draw-lines-on-the-mini-map and https://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/showthread.php?497544-How-do-you-draw-lines-on-the-new-minimap . so no drawing for me then :/